# Updating datatables with ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, datatables

I am using spring MVC 4 and dandelion jsp datatables.

I wish to update a column in the table's column (progress percentage) every X seconds without reloading the entire page (probably via ajax).

The update should refer to the controller each X seconds, fetch the requested data and update the column with the results.

I tried to add a simple ajax for external div (not within the table) as a start but it seems to corrupt the table:

```
<script>
function testAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajaxtest.html',
        success : function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

```
<script>
    var intervalId = 0;
    intervalId = setInterval(testAjax, 6000);
</script>

<body>
    <div id="result">123</div>
    <div class="container-table">
    <datatables:table id="listRecordsModel" data="${listModel}" row="record"  cssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="2" scrollX="120%" 
                        theme="bootstrap2" pageable="true" info="true">
                        <datatables:column title="Record ID" property="recordId"/>
.
.
.
```

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxtest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
    String getTime() {
    System.out.println("------------------------------------random");////////////////////
    return "WORKS!!!";
```

Is there a simple way doing that?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I don't see that the string `123` is changing to `WORKS!!!`. The table become wider (full screen) and the scrollX disappear and the memory seems to be full after some time. It seems that it doing something (although I don't see the system print from the controller) .

Comment: Can be due to the incoming html design. Check the css for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - the path to the html file was wrong and met with the initial method in the controller so the page loaded from scratch every 6 seconds.

I replaced `url : 'ajaxtest.html',` with `url : '../../ajaxtest.html',`.

Thanks anyway!